# Is it possible to use .a library in swift project

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS Objective C library (.a file) and set of header files (.h files). The are intended to be used in Objective C iOS applications.

Is it possible to use them in Swift project? I have read "mix and match" documentation, but they talk about importing .m-files or frameworks, not about binary library (.a-file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can. Drag the folder containing the .a file and the headers into your project (yes, copy them). Make sure they show up in the "Linked Frameworks and Target" section.

As you can see from the screen shot below, you can mix and match .tbd files, frameworks, and .a libraries.

[image]

Comment: I dont think this works on latest XCode 11 in a swift project, at less for me it shows `No such module 'xyzSDK'`.